# Prediction with linear regression is very inaccurate

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression

This is the csv that im using https://gist.github.com/netj/8836201 currently, im trying to **predict** the **variety** which is **categorical data** with **linear regression** but somehow the prediction is very very inaccurate. While you know, the actual label is just combination of 0.0 and 1. but the prediction is 0.numbers and 1.numbers even with minus numbers which in my opinion is very inaccurate, what part did i make the mistake and what is the solution for this inaccuracy? this is the assignment my teacher gave me, he said we could predict the categorical data with linear regression not only logistic regression

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import metrics

path= r"D:\python projects\iris.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path)
array = df.values
X = array[:,0:3]
y = array[:,4]
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
ohe = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
y = le.fit_transform(y)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)
y = ohe.fit_transform(y).toarray()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
sc = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
y_train = sc.fit_transform(y_train)
model = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': X_test.flatten(), 'Predicted': y_pred.flatten()})
```

the output :

```
y_pred
Out[46]: 
array([[-0.08676055,  0.43120144,  0.65555911],
       [ 0.11735424,  0.72384335,  0.1588024 ],
       [ 1.17081347, -0.24484483,  0.07403136],
X_test
Out[61]: 
array([[-0.09544771, -0.58900572,  0.72247648],
       [ 0.14071157, -1.98401928,  0.10361279],
       [-0.44968663,  2.66602591, -1.35915595],
```

Comment: You used linear regression. You got back what looks like a linear regression result to me. The result of linear regression would be a function that produces a linear combination of vectors. Furthermore, it looks like your result is aligning with the desired one, in the sense that the highest values match the 1s.

Comment: yes, but the prediction is too inaccurate in my opinion so i feel there's a mistake that i made without realizing it or maybe i did not know what mistake i made

Comment: What method are you using to measure accuracy?

Comment: did you measure your score for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Linear Regression is used to predict **continuous** output data. As you correctly said, you are trying to predict **categorical** (discrete) output data. Essentially, you want to be doing classification instead of regression - linear regression is not appropriate for this.

As you also said, logistic regression can and should be used instead as it is applicable to classification tasks.

Comment: where do you see categorical data in his case? the `X_test`data has values like: '-0.09544771, -1.98401928'

Comment: if you apply standardscaler and only have `0` and `1` in your original data, you will also only have two different values in your preprocessed data...something is wrong here

Comment: @PV8: You are correct that `X_test`is real valued, though X in this case appears to be the input whereas they are trying to predict y. y is a label encoded (and, one-hot encoded, for some reason) categorical variable, corresponding to the 'variety' column in the linked CSV, if I understood the question correctly.